# How to multithread in PowerBuidler

Tags: multithreading, powerbuilder

how can I open a window on a separate thread?

w_main

open process window btn code:

```
//instance variable
stopper = false

if SharedObjectRegister("w_sep_thread", "SendThread") = success! then
    messagebox('', 'Success')
else
    messagebox('', 'Unsuccessful')
end if

open(w_sep_thread)
```

stop process btn code:

```
stopper = true
```

w_sep_thread

start process btn code:

```
int i
do while w_main.stopper = false
    sleep(1)
    st_1.text = string(i + 1)
loop

messagebox('', 'Stopped')
```

If I click the start process btn both the UIs still freeze, but the `SharedObjectRegister` function returns `success`

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Pollach says "Mutli-threading in PB would only be done using NVUO's not Window classes". I hope it helps this thread: [click here](https://scn.sap.com/thread/3652031)